# LARAVEL: how to send data from view to controller

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, laravel

I need to send a value of `<input type='CHIPS'>`

from **add.blade.php** to **userController@add.php**

this is the code of **add.blade.php** file:

```
<div class="container">
        <form method="POST" action="{!! url('add') !!}" id="ajouter" accept-charset="UTF-8">

            <label for="nom">Entrez votre nom : </label>
            <input name="name" type="text"  id="name">

            <input name="email" type="email" id="email">

            <input name="password" type="password" id="password">

            <label for="permution">saisier les parmutions : </label>

            <div class="chips" name="permution"></div>

            <input class="btn-info" type="submit" value="Envoyer !">

            <div id="permution" name="permution">

            </div>

        </form>
    </div>
```

and this is the *scripte* in **add.blade.php** file : 
where i got data from chips_form and I set them in a new value of type String

```
<!--Import jQuery before materialize.js-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="css/materialize/js/materialize.min.js"></script>


    <script>
        $(function() {

            var data = $('.chips').material_chip();
            var dataString = JSON.stringify(data);

        });
    </script>
```

**route.php file**:

```
Route::get('/add', 'UsersController@add_form');
Route::post('/add', 'UsersController@add');
```

**userController.php** file :

```
    public function add_form()
        {
            return view('add');
        }


        public function add(Request $request)
        {
            $name = $request->input('name');
            $email=$request->input('email');
            $password = $request->input('password');
            $cryptPassword= bcrypt($password);

            //Insert SQL Request
}
```

Comment: You will need to have an `input` field with the `name` chips.

Comment: It is the basic. Read documentation. It is simple. For sure this thread is somewhere on stackoverflow.

Comment: @Laerte I need to send " var dataString " to Controller and use it there

Comment: Hey @aladin: this question is very unclear. I'm afraid you won't get any meaningful answers unless you articulate your question a bit better. Meanwhile, why don't you check out Laravel's documentation at https://laravel.com/docs/5.5?

Answer (score 1):

To send the contenct of dataString to the controller, you can create a hidden input in the form, and set its value using jQuery.

First, add an input to the form:

```
<input id="ichips" type="hidden" name="chips">
```

Then, set its value using jQuery:

```
var data = $('.chips').material_chip();
var dataString = JSON.stringify(data);
$("#ichips").val(dataString);
```

When the user send the form, the value will be in the hidden input.

Comment: I try it , and when I submit my form , I got null as value in "ichips" 

PS: I added 'dd($request->all())' to controller ( to test)  ,          

and before submit I filled the chips form .

Comment: To make a test, change the code to `$("#ichips").val("TEST");` and check if the value is present in `dd($request->all());`.

Comment: yes I check it , the avlue TEST is present (I got ''chips'' => ''test''), but when i check it with dataString I got ''ichips''=>''''

Comment: So, the problem is that `dataString` is null or empty. You should check if `data` has a valid JSON string.